# How to extract citation from pdf files without header or footer?

Tags: python, regex, citations

I need to extract all citations from multiple PDF files (more than 400 files), and I was able to do so using regular expressions and it worked, only there's a problem for some of the situations where half of them is at the end of the page, and the other half at the beginning of another page. In this cases the footer of the page is included and I want a way to extract the citation without the footer.

Here's an example in one of the files :
[image]

The yellow part is what i want to extract.
The yellow + the green part is what i'm getting

Regular expression used :

```
(\([A-Z][^\s0-9]+(\d{4}|[;,]|and|al|[A-Z][^\s0-9]+|\.|\s|-\n[a-z]+)+\d{4}[a-z]?\))
```

And

```
([A-Z][^\s0-9,;]+(and|al|[A-Z][^\s0-9]+|\.|\s|-\n[a-z]+)+\(\d{4}[a-z]?\))
```

Comment: An image of text is not very helpful. Ideally we can copy the string to be used in our testing. Please copy/paste the text (several examples preferably) into your question and clearly indicate the expected output.

Comment: If I were to guess, it's the way the PDF is formatted. The text "Savary and Waszczuk (2012)" is probably not sequential as you might expect it to be. The footer text is probably in-between the two halves of the text you want. I'm not sure if there's anything you can do about that.

Comment: @JeffC is right.  Remember that a PDF was not designed as a text-storage container.  It was designed as a pretend printer, capturing in image form what would have gone on paper.  You may just have to handle these by hand.

Comment: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W13-2414.pdf      that's the link to the pdf file @JeffC

Comment: @dev If you search for "Savary and Waszczuk (2012)" in the PDF using Find, it doesn't find it. That seems to indicate what I said before is true. You probably can use a regex for most citations but those that span the two columns you'll probably have to locate/fix by hand.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thank you